# Python pandas find element of one column in list of elements of another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, isin

Here is my problem, where I want to find element of column A in list of elements of column B of a dataframe. As a result I want to to only keep those rows, where the element in A was found:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],
                   'B': [1, 3]
                 })
result = df[df.A.isin(df.B)]

>>> result
   A  B
0  1  1
```

works fine, but what I really want is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2],
                   'B': [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
                 })
result = df[df.A.isin(df.B)]

>>> result
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B]
Index: []
```

Which does not work as the elements from A are not compared with the elements of the lists in column B but with the whole list?

What I would like to have as a result is:

```
>>> result
   A       B
0  1  [1, 2]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `apply`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row['A'] in row['B'], axis=1)]
```

or zip comprehension:

```
df[[a in b for a,b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]]
```

output:

```
   A       B
0  1  [1, 2]
```

Comment: list comprehension is the way to go here

Comment: Used apply now and it works fine. Is the zip comprehension more efficient?